# servicestack userauthid is type of string but it actually is int

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-auth

Is there any cases where IAuthSession.UserAuthId is something else than int or can I just safely assume it is always int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Type of UserAuthId is dependent on the Auth Repository used, e.g. if you're using an `OrmLiteAuthRepository` it will always be an `int`.

Comment: great. does it depends if in future I will enable FacebookAuthProvider feature or GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider feature?

Comment: @Roman it's dependent on Auth Repositories, not Auth Providers which have no effect